# CSS child selector (>) doesn't work with IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

The following CSS works well under firefox but doesn't work under IE browser, Why?
Also, how can I make only the elements, directly under the parent element, be affected by CSS?

CSS:

```
.box{font:24px;}
.box>div{font:18px}
.box>div>div{font:12px;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
   level1
   <div>
      level2
      <div> level3</div>
      <div> level3</div>
   </div>
   <div>
      level2
      <div> level3</div>
      <div> level3</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Internet Explorer supports the child selector (`>`) since version 7, but only in Standards mode. Make sure you are using [a Doctype that triggers standards mode](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/).

If you are targeting IE6 then you are out of luck. You need to either depend on JS or use descendant selectors.

```
a>b { foo }
```

becomes

```
a b { foo }
a * b { reverse-of-foo }
```

Comment: Sorry to resurrect, but I'm at a loss with the `reverse-of-foo` part :P

Comment: @Baumr the `a b` rule will declare properties intended for the descendant; `a * b` rule should declare properties over-riding the rule above.

Answer (score 1):

The child selector is not supported at all by IE6 and only partly by IE7.

[**Quirksmode.org: Child selector**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selector_child.html)

[**CSS Compatibility tables**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

there is, sadly, no way to do this except to "un-declate" the definitions for all grandchildren.

Answer (score -2):

I may be wrong about what you are looking for but this is how I would tackle your problem:

```
.box {font:24px;}
.box div {font:18px}
.box div div {font:12px;}
```

This will work fine for you example, however be aware that if you have another .box with div's in it they will be affected as well.