# em/% not resizing the font

Tags: css, font-size

I am having an issue with my responsive font-size. I set the overall font-size to 62.5% and now I am trying to set an h2 to 57px (so 5.7 em)but it won't change. Same for the percentages. If I use Px, it will change but then of course it won't size with my page.

```
/* Import fonts */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One);
/* End import fonts */

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 62.5%; /*10 pixels*/
    font-family: "Julius Sans One", sans-serif;
    font-weight:normal;
}

#titles {
    margin: auto;
    width:92.08%;
}

#titles header > h2 {
    font-size: 5.7em;
    color: #61bf82;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you declared a doctype for the page?
I noticed that adding:
`<!DOCTYPE html>`
above `<html>`
showed difference.

Without adding this it went into quirks mode and did not show what I was expecting.
This is caused by the child selector (>)

Perhaps this question can be considered a duplicate to:
[CSS child selector (>) doesn't work with IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402737/css-child-selector-doesnt-work-with-ie)

Comment: I did declare the doctype. I discovered that when I leave my font-size: 100%; instead of 62.5%, everything will cascade through and I can work with ems. As soon as I change it to 62.5, it won't do anything. Any thoughts?