# css style is not setting back after h:over

Tags: javascript, css

In my application i have the following code.

```
.test>div {
    display: none;
}
.test:hover>div {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 9999;
    height: 100px;
}
```

When I mouseover test a popup will open and mouseout it will hide.

But after mouseover and mouseout the  `.test:hover>div` is still retains and not hides. When i inspect the element, the `.test:hover>div` is still active even after mouseout of `.test`.

[CSS child selector (>) doesn't work with IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402737/css-child-selector-doesnt-work-with-ie)
in the above link, css selector unable to select, but here it select and not applying any other style after that.
This works fine in all the browsers except IE8.

Comment: try .test > div:hover

Comment: I want to hide the .test>div on mouseout of .test

Comment: What browser are you using? It works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/jwfbq41s/

Comment: nope, he cant hover display none, is your div overlowing parent?

Comment: my requirement is when i mouse over the div i need to show a child div of class test. so i wrote the css for showing code in hover and it is working fine.

Comment: @JBux. sorry i forgot to mention. this caught only in IE8

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269831/hover-effects-not-working-with-ie8

Comment: @user833985 I don't have access to IE8 at the moment, but is it functioning as you wish in other browsers? Chrome/Firefox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS child selector (>) doesn't work with IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402737/css-child-selector-doesnt-work-with-ie)

Comment: @JBux. yes it works fine in all other browsers.

Comment: My duplicate is very similar to the answer from @Paulie_D's suggestion, but specifically for the direct child selector

Comment: @paulie_D I checked the link but it didnt help me.

Comment: Its working, I tried checking in IE Tester IE8,9,10..

Comment: Provide the html in the question and make a fiddle replicating your error.  In it's current form there is nothing that we can replicate using your current code

Answer (score 0):

I did an example and display:none is not a good ideia because div is removed from dom. The explanation of mozilla: Turns off the display of an element (it has no effect on layout); all descendant elements also have their display turned off. The document is rendered as though the element did not exist.

Then I used background:transparent to element exists, but you can try with visibility.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="test">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

and my css:

```
.test{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:solid 1px;
}

.test > div{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:transparent;
}

.test > div:hover{

    background-color:red;
}
```

and the example working at jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xukLc5h1/

Comment: I want to show and hide a div when i mouse over and mouseout test. here you are changing when mouse over .test >div

Comment: Explain better, you want to show a div when mouseover and hide a div when mouseout?

Comment: Invert background-color of div and div:hover. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/5qgouxLp/

Comment: yes. I  want to show a div when mouseover and hide a div when mouseout

Comment: the same concept i applied. when hover display:inline-block otherwise display:none